# xsl to transform svn log grouped by author

Tags: xml, svn, xslt

I have a Subversion changelog in xml format, created with

```
svn log http://svnurl -r {2014-01-01}:{2014-05-01} --xml > changelog.xml
```

This gives me an XML file with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<log>
<logentry
   revision="1234">
<author>foo</author>
<date>2014-02-14T13:19:30.288981Z</date>
<msg>Commit by foo</msg>
</logentry>
<logentry
   revision="1235">
<author>bar</author>
<date>2014-02-14T13:57:54.506257Z</date>
<msg>Commit1 by bar</msg>
</logentry>
<logentry
   revision="1236">
<author>bar</author>
<date>2014-03-14T13:57:54.506257Z</date>
<msg>Commit2 by bar</msg>
</logentry>
</log>
```

I would like to transform this to a HTML file:

```
<html>
<body>
<h2>Change log by author</h2>
<ul>
  <li><h3>foo</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Commit by foo</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><h3>bar</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Commit1 by bar</li>
      <li>Commit2 by bar</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

This is what I came up with after a couple of hours of googling and stackoverflowing (no previous xml knowledge):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <body>
        <h2>Change log</h2>
        <ul>
            <xsl:template match="/">
                    <xsl:for-each-group select="log/logentry" group-by="author">
                        <li><h3><xsl:value-of select="author"/></h3>
                            <ul>
                                <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                                    <li><xsl:value-of select="msg"/></li>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </xsl:for-each-group>
            </xsl:template>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I tested this with XML Notepad but unfortunately I get no output. Also Internet Explorer and Chrome don't transform the file. What's the obvious thing that I'm missing here?

EDIT: I dumped *Microsoft XML Notepad* and installed a 30 day evaluation version of *Altova Missionkit*. With that, and while following an example about *The Muenchian Method* I found on http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html, I came up with this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

 <xsl:key name="changelog-by-author" match="logentry" use="author" />
 <xsl:template match="log">
    <xsl:for-each select="logentry[count(. | key('changelog-by-author', author)[1]) = 1]">
                <xsl:sort select="author" />
                <h2><xsl:value-of select="author" /></h2>
                <ul>
                    <xsl:for-each select="key('changelog-by-author', author)">
                        <xsl:sort select="msg" />
                        <li><xsl:value-of select="msg" /></li>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </ul>
            </xsl:for-each>    
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The resulting HTML is now what I was looking for.

What wasn't in my original question, but what I would like to add, is the revision number. I'll add that when I find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working in the browsers because of lack of support for XSLT 2.0. As of this date, Internet Explorer and Chrome *don't yet have native support for XSLT 2.0*. For it towork in these browsers you will have to use *Muenchian grouping* in XSLT 1.0 to group your log-entries, since XSLT 1.0 doesn't support `for-each-group`.

Besides that, your transformation is incorrect because the HTML tags are outside the `<xsl:template>`. If you place them inside the template it will work (in a XSLT 2.0 compatible processor):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" ... >
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <html >
        <body> ... </body>
    </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

An alternative way of doing the transformation is to use literal result elements. In this case you don't need a full XSLT template. You should place the XSLT namespace and version before you use the XSL tags in your document:

```
<html xsl:version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <body>
        <h2>Change log</h2>
        <ul>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="log/logentry" group-by="author">
                <li><h3><xsl:value-of select="author"/></h3>
                    <ul>
                        <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                            <li><xsl:value-of select="msg"/></li>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: When I do that, I get this XSL output in XML Notepad:
Error Transforming XML 
'group-by' is not a recognized extension element. An error occurred at ...\changelog.xsl(13,13).

Comment: Never mind, I never heard of _Muenchian grouping_ before, I'm going to look into that.

Comment: Your answer didn't answer my question directly, but I am going to accept it anyway, because you have set me on the path for Muenchian grouping, which I wouldn't have known about otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I totally ditched Windows and I'm now on Linux. For future reference, this is how I transformed the XML file as a bash oneliner. I'm posting it here because I searched on StackOverflow and couldn't find either any good questions or any good anwers.

```
java -jar ~/Downloads/SaxonHE9-5-1-6J/saxon9he.jar \
    changelog.xml changelogbyauthor.xsl | tidy -ic -o changelog.html
```

- `saxon9he.jar`: included in Saxon HE, download from http://saxon.sourceforge.net/, detailed usage is described on http://saxon.sourceforge.net/saxon7.7/using-xsl.html
- `changelog.xml`: created with `svn log --xml`
- `changelogbyauthor.xsl`: the above XSLT 2.0 file
- `tidy`: this is HTML Tidy, to get cleaner HTML with proper indentation and stuff.